# Purpose of additional parameters in Quantization Nodes of TensorFlow Quantization Aware Training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Currently, I am trying to understand quantization aware training in TensorFlow. I understand, that fake quantization nodes are required to gather dynamic range information as a calibration for the quantization operation. When I compare the same model once as "plain" Keras model and once as quantization aware model, the latter has more parameters, which makes sense since we need to store the minimum and maximum values for activations during the quantization aware training.

Consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
def get_model(in_shape):
  inpt = layers.Input(shape=in_shape)
  dense1 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(inpt)
  dense2 = layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(dense1)
  out = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(dense2)

  model = Model(inpt, out)

  return model
```

The model has the following summary:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 256)               200960    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 235,146
Trainable params: 235,146
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

However, if i make my model optimization aware, it prints the following summary:

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model

# q_aware stands for for quantization aware.
q_aware_model = quantize_model(standard)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
quantize_layer (QuantizeLaye (None, 784)               3         
_________________________________________________________________
quant_dense_3 (QuantizeWrapp (None, 256)               200965    
_________________________________________________________________
quant_dense_4 (QuantizeWrapp (None, 128)               32901     
_________________________________________________________________
quant_dense_5 (QuantizeWrapp (None, 10)                1295      
=================================================================
Total params: 235,164
Trainable params: 235,146
Non-trainable params: 18
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have two questions in particular:

1. What is the purpose of the `quantize_layer` with 3 parameters after the Input layer?
2. Why do we have 5 additional non-trainable parameters per layer and what are they used for exactly?

I appreciate any hint or further material that helps me (and others that stumble upon this question) understand quantization aware training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The quantize layer is used to convert the float inputs to int8. The quantization parameters are used for output min/max and zero point calculations.
2. Quantized Dense Layers need a few additional parameters: min/max for kernel and min/max/zero-point for output activations.